Area 51 Milestone: Avid site users reaches "excellent" status: August 2013
I just noticed we reached another site milestone.
Our site now meets all the Area 51 requirements for achieving "excellent" status when it comes to avid users. I.e., we have 5+ 3,000 rep users; 10+ 2,000 rep users, and 150+ 200 rep users. It was a year ago that we reached "okay" status.
I've seen a real energy around this site, particularly over the last couple of months as several new users have got extensively involved. This has translated into more questions, more answers, and, importantly, more voting. I think this is really encouraging to see. If this momentum persists, I imagine we can start making our other statistics look better. 
In particular, keeping the questions and answers at a high rate means that we're generating lots of content which in turn translates into more visits per day.



I wish I could upvote this more than once!!! I agree completly Jeromy, I am quite pleased with the site's recent growth. Great work everyone!
